# Can't access a specific database from phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I've installed WAMP on a computer some months ago. Now I'm trying to use it and I was trying to surf the databases using phpMyAdmin. So I went to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and it showed me the databases.

The problem is: I can se all databases except for one that displays this error:

> `#1045` - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My `config.inc.php` file has no password set.
The weird thing about this is that when I get to the MySQL console (`C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin\mysql`) I can surf through the database without a problem.

Any suggestion on how I can see the database using phpMyAdmin?